# Overheating issues, even after suggested remedies

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, desktop-computer, overheating

So my computer/Server is overheating on a regular basis, I thought that the issue might be the thermal compound on the heatsink, so I have replaced that (just 20 minutes ago), that seems to have done nothing. Also I used to keep the side off of the case and point a fan directly into it, having returned the side of the case I see no difference, I also removed all dust from the inside while replacing the thermal compound, and so far the situation seems to have only worsened. What should I do?

---

**EDIT:**

Specs obtained by Speccy:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
| CPU      | Intel XEON Irwindale 3.2GHz                |
| RAM      | 2x Samsung 1024MB DDR1 (model unknown ATM) |
| MOBO     | Supermicro X6DAL                           |
| CHIPSET  | Intel E7525                                |
| Graphics | NVIDIA GeForce 210 -- GPU : GT218          |
| Network  | Ralink RT61 Turbo Wireless LAN Card        |
+----------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Temperature Readings:

```
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|             Activity             | CPU Temp. |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
| Idle (Nothing Running)           | 54C       |
| Idle (A few apps. Running)       | 57C       |
| Browsing The web (No BG Apps)    | 62C       |
| Browsing the web (A few BG Apps) | 70C       |
| Watching YouTube (No BG Apps)    | 66C       |
| Watching YouTube (A few BG Apps) | 74C       |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```

I was trying to get a reading for the CPU usage but it is very difficult to get a solid reading since it is constantly jumping around. If I am not doing anything it is about 0-5%, but If I am doing anything It is anything from 5% to 80%, with about zero consistency; I did manage to get the following screenshot of Task Manager > Performance while watching YouTube. The RAM usage however is a bit easier to read and is often around 900MB with a bit of activity and around 1100MB while running some apps.

[image: 1]

In response to asking what the use actually is, I use it to run an apache WAMP server to host my own website (as you could figure from my SO account), Since it is running W7 Home Premium I use it for personal uses at times to, such as browsing the web, watching YT etc. Up until now it has functioned with no issues at all and not overheated once, even when I tried to play rather intense games It held in and didn't overheat. It has got to a point now where I have my window open 24/7, and point a rather large fan directly into the side of the case.

I haven't got any accurate data for ambient room temp. but I will go and borrow a thermometer from the kitchen to get a reading, and will update this ASAP.

Couple pictures taken with an old webcam:

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Do the fans work properly? Fan failure seems to be the last thing people look at.

Comment: Is your server doing what it is supposed to do? There could be malware or stuck process that is wasting CPU and cause your server to overload.

Comment: Lets see it, let us see more and know more, you have not provided information enough to be able to assist?  You could link to a pic that shows your general airflow that your using? specs on the machine (all of them inc. heat sink , any OC ammounts)?  Actual temps your getting? Cpu usage ? What activity does the machine participate in? What is occuring that you identified as overheating? What are your ambient temps your dealing with?  What OS are you running? What other things did you check?

Comment: @Ramhound Becuase the server is beeping at me, and at the same time SpeedFan shows temperatures above 75C.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don't think they're problemed, they seem to be functioning as they should be, There is consistent airflow from the CPU fans.

Comment: @someuser It is functioning correctly and serving my website as it always has, only recently it has been getting excessively hot, and as stated overheating.

Comment: @Psycogeek  I will make an edit to my OP to include requested details.

Comment: if you put your hand in front of the fans while the computer is running and overheating, do you feel significantly hot air being blown on to your hand? If not, this means that there is a heat transfer issue from the cpu to the heatsink

Comment: @Blaine No there isn't, I'm going to add a couple images to the OP, and if you check them out in a minute you'll see why.

Comment: your cpu Tcase rating is about 72C. This is lower than allowable core temp. It is unclear where you are getting the actual measurement, but my recollection is that this is usually a derived measurement and there may be a margin of error. If your core is running at or near the Tcase rating, I suspect you aren't actually overheating. The CPU will shut down at 100 or so and about 125 is the thermal limit for CMOS (if I recall correctly)

Comment: @Yorik The reason I suspect the overheating is because when SpeedFan says the CPU is 75C (apprx.), the computer starts making a high pitch whistling, and everything slows to a halt to reduce load on the CPU. Also when I replaced the thermal compound yesterday the heat sink was **Very** hot, and it had only been on for about 10 minutes previously, so there is a lot of heat there.

Comment: whistling? squealing could be a fan bearings? incessant beeping comming from the MB beep speaker could certannly be from the motherboard , and could be about heat, with bios thermal "warning" settings (adjustable). while it should not be 75*c (with that config) unless your overclocking, that is still "working but high" temps. What if it is comming based on other sencors or issues (even say ecc)? Chipset temps? lots of i/o through the chipset?  Explore the temps and temp settings, and other settings, while IN the bios as a start.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yeah its the MoBo squeeler thing, and when I boot up the screen says `No BIOS installed`; correct me if I'm wrong, but it needs a BIOS to boot up, right?

Comment: yes, having that error may mean other things (donno what) like many errors.